# Where and how should I write or set the class of trigger processing of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: cluster-computing, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I tried to create trigger using the following command of Apache IoTDB:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `alert-listener-sgld1s1` AFTER INSERT ON root.sgl.d1.s1 AS 'org.apache.iotdb.db.engine.trigger.example.AlertListener' WITH ( 'lo' = '0', 'hi'= '100.0').
```

However I got an error said that

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.iotdb.db.engine.trigger.example.AlertListener.
```

I wonder what did this jar package ClusterAlertingExample.jar do? Should I write the trigger processing class in the ClusterAlertingExample.jar package myself?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Answer (score 0):

The class names specified after `AS` is the fully qualified class name of the class in the jar package you are using for Apache IoTDB. You can use `implement trigger` class to create an interface, set a trigger type, packed  into jar package and register it. You can also refer to the instruction in the user manual of the official website.